# How to add 0s to a numeric attribute so that all numbers in the attribute are 10 digits in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a numeric attribute that contains IDs in a table in my database. However, the IDs are not of the same length (e.g. 54261, 73284619, 3723). I want all of them to be in the same length by adding 0s in front of them so that all of them are 10 digits (e.g. 000054261, 0073284619, 0000003723). I'm wondering if I can write a SQL query to achieve this or I have to do this in Excel.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: To add leading 0's, you first have to cast the integer values to varchar.

Comment: Can't you add the zeroes in your presentation layer if you need them?

Answer (score 0):

Usually functions like LPAD, RPAD are recommended to achieve your usecase

Try  something like below

```
     Select   TO_NUMBER(LPAD(TO_CHAR(ID) , 10,'0')) FROM 
      DUAL;
```

LPAD will add zeroes to the left of the string id to make it a 10 digit and RPAD likewise is vice versa adding 0s to the right

Note: may not be supported accross all dbs but mainly oracle, postgres etc.